# ROR Access module function in a scope into a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord

I try to create a module to manage access depending of an entity field on several models.
The name of my entity field depends on the schema of the current model which call it.

My Module is :

```
 module Modules::EntityManagement
        extend ActiveSupport::Concern

        def entity_field_name
            self.class.connection.schema_search_path.split(",").first == 'public' ? 'entity_id' : 'entity_id__c'
        end


        included do
            scope :myscope, lambda {
                where('WHERE ? = ?', self.entity_field_name, 1) 
            }
        end
    end
```

When I call this on any model
`Mymodel.myscope`

It returns an error

```
undefined method `entity_field_name' for #<Class:0x007ff62da60150>
```

I tried a lot of different syntax, but nothing works.

How can I use a dynamic field name based on database schema in a module's scope ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap `entity_field_name` so it is a class method:

```
class_methods do
  def entity_field_name
    self.connection.schema_search_path.split(",").first == 'public' ? 'entity_id' : 'entity_id__c'
  end
end
```

If you also need at the instance level, add:

```
def entity_field_name
  self.class.entity_field_name
end
```

Comment: Great. Thank a lot for your quick answer.
Wrapping into class_methods do end 
do the job.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use `delegate :entity_field_name, to: :class`?

Comment: you definitely could :) matter of taste ;)

Comment: Okay I thought there was a tricky part or hidden feature there, thank you :)